# C# How do I set up a form close event on MessageBox

Tags: c#, forms, messagebox

I'm sure this is probably been asked many times, but I can't locate it. I have some code that opens messagebox based on two outcomes to a question, Right or Wrong. Currently, clicking okay on the messagebox returns to the form with the question. What I want is to have one of two actions occur, I just don't know where to start to make it happen.

If right, when messagebox closes I want the question to be refreshed. If wrong, I want the messagebox to close, perform as action (loop), and allow another try.

I can't find an event to control the messagebox form closing.

Can anyone share some advice? Thanks for your time.

```
double userAnswer = double.Parse(txtResult.Text); if (Question.CheckIfRight(userAnswer)) MessageBox.Show("Right!!"); else MessageBox.Show("Wrong");
```

Comment: Post code and probably you will get the answer in no time.

Comment: it seems like that you want to create a custom message box window with a simple delegate (such as Action) to be invoked when closed....

Comment: Oh... you don't need that event, you just need the Question.CheckIfRight boolean, if true, change question, otherwise, don't change

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like your question is more about program flow.

```
private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var userAnswer = double.Parse(txtResult.Text);

    if (!Question.CheckIfRight(userAnswer))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong");
        return;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Right!!");
    RefreshQuestion();
}
```

**Update:**

Keep in mind that `MessageBox.Show("Right!!")` will block the calling code and wait until the user clicks the OK-button before it resumes to `RefreshQuestion();` so you shouldn't need pursue any events for when it closes.

Answer (score 0):

`MessageBox.Show(...)` returns one of values from [`DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration. You can you use this to check which one of the options provided a user clicked on.

So the code can look as follows:

```
double userAnswer = double.Parse(txtResult.Text); 
DialogResult dr;

if (Question.CheckIfRight(userAnswer)) 
{
  dr = MessageBox.Show("Right"); 
}
else 
{
  dr = MessageBox.Show("Wrong");
}

if(dr == DialogResult.OK) 
{
    // Your "action" goes here
}
```

That way you can check when `MessageBox` was closed and what button user clicked to close it. Based on that you can carry on in your program the way you want.